# How to store and access images in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

How can I store an image in redux and later access it in another component? My goal is to use the TextInput to save the image url and show the actual image in another component. I'm not sure how to access the image from Profile in Main. Here's my code for saving the image in Profile:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Button, Vibrate } from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {saveProfile} from '../redux/actions';

import Settings from './Settings';

class Profile extends React.Component {
  
  saveProfile=(yourProfile)=>{
    var saveProfile=this.props.yourProfile
    this.props.dispatch(saveProfile(yourProfile));
  }
  
  handleName=(name)=>{
    this.props.dispatch(saveProfile(name));
  }
  
  handlePhone=(phone)=>{
    this.props.dispatch(saveProfile(phone));
  }
  
  handleEmail=(email)=>{
    this.props.dispatch(saveProfile(email));
  }
  
  handleAvatar=(avatar)=>{
    this.props.dispatch(saveProfile(avatar));
  }
  
  handleVibrate = (vibrate) => {
    if (vibrate===true){
      Vibration.vibrate(DURATION); 
    } else {
      Vibration.cancel()
    } this.setState({
      vibrate
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="name"
          onChangeText={this.handleName}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="phone"
          keyboardType="phone-pad"
          onChangeText={this.handlePhone}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="email"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          onChangeText={this.handleEmail}
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="avatarUrl"
          keyboardType="url"
          onChangeText={this.handleAvatar}
        />
        <Switch
          value={this.state.vibrate}
          onValueChange={this.handleVibrate}
        />
        <Button
          title="Save"
          onPress={this.saveProfile}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mp(state){
  return {
    yourProfile:state.saveProfile.yourProfile
  }
}

export default connect(mp)(yourProfile);
```

And here is my code for displaying the image in Main:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, Image, View, Vibrate } from 'react-native';

import Settings from './Settings';
import Profile from './Profile';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {saveProfile, saveSettings} from '../redux/actions';

class Main extends React.Component {
  state={
    avatar: 
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          source={this.state.avatar}
          style={{width: 300, height: 300}}
        />
        <Text>{name}</Text>
        <Text>{phone}</Text>
        <Text>{email}</Text>
        <Settings />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

function mp(state){
  return{
    
  }
}

export default connect(mp)(Main);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your avatar is relatively small, you might want to save it in Base64 format, and use that in your Redux store

In order to load it up in the <Image> component, it must be in this format:

**data:image/png;base64,**<your base64 image here>

You have to add the encoding method to the source property of <Image>

```
<Image
   source= {uri:'data:image/png;base64,' + {this.state.avatar}}
   style={{width: 300, height: 300}}
/>
```

And it would be a good practice to access it through props rather than state.

Answer (score -1):

> Steps to store something in the redux store

1. Dispatch an action with the data (your image URL).
2. Create a reducer and save the data in a store variable.
3. Connect the react component in which you want to access the data from the redux store
4. Now the data from redux store variable is available in your component as props.

---

This questions more seems like you want a tutorial rather than a solution to a problem.

Go through [this](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact) official documentation. `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` is the key to your problem.

Comment: I need to show the image which url would be entered in the profile form which I already have. My main question is how to get access to the image that would be saved when url entered?

Comment: Simply store the form variables into the redux store and then access those variables in the main page. Sorry, but I think still I didn't get your point :(

Comment: I've got the first part, but do I do the accessing part for the image? I don't understand how to pass the image variable from profile to main page?